# Get product collection by Country of Manufacture in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes

I tried the following code but it's not working for me.

```
/**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollection;

    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollection = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollectionByUSA(){
        $collection = $this->_productCollection->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('country_of_manufacture');
        return $collection;
    }
```

Any help on this?

Comment: For which country you want to filter the product collection? By USA only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below function instead of yours:

```
public function getProductCollectionByUSA(){
    $collection = $this->_productCollection->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('country_of_manufacture','US');
    return $collection;
}
```

Flush the cache and test. Assuming you are getting correct product collection.